# Celery: Instance becomes slow after a week or two

Tags: python, django, celery

I have a django app with a celery instance that consumes and synchronizes a very large amount of data multiple times a day. I’ll note that I am using asyncio to call a library for an API that wasn’t made for async. I’ve noticed that after a week or so the server becomes painfully slow and can even become days behind in tasks after a few weeks.

Looking at my host’s profiler the RAM or CPU usage isn’t going wild, but I know it’s becoming slower and slower every week because that celery instance also handles emails at a specific time which send out hours and hours later as the weeks pass.

Restarting the instance seems to fix everything instantly, leading me to believe I have something like a memory leak (but the ram isn’t going wild) or something like unclosed threads (I have no idea how to detect this and the CPU isn’t going wild).

Any ideas?

Comment: Does it swap when it is slow?

Comment: @DejanLekic sorry, swap?

Comment: are you using RabbitMQ or redis?

Comment: @NotSoShabby Redis

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a very familiar issue with celery which is still opened on Github - [here](https://github.com/celery/celery/issues/4185)

We are experiencing similar issues and unfortunately didnt find a good workaround.

It seems that [this](https://github.com/celery/celery/issues/4185#issuecomment-373755206) comment found the issue, but we didnt have time to find and implement a workaround, so i cant say for sure - Please update if you found something helpful to solve. As this is Open Source, no one is responsible for making a fix but the community itself :)

Comment: I’m thinking of moving my worker logic into go-celery. I wonder if that will help.

Comment: Sounds cool if you are able to just switch up your logic quickly, that sounds like its worth a shot

Comment: It will likely take a bit of work without being able to easily use the django orm. The latest update in that thread you linked looks hopeful but I’m not quite ready to update myself.

Comment: can you please mark as the answer if it answered your question (even if for now)